# Scope of the directive is used instead of the scope of the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controller, directive

In my project, I want to access to the $scope of a controller, but, since my scope is inside a directive, the $scope of the directive is used.

Here is a perfect example of what's happened. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrmeZw?editors=1010

If I replace the `<card-panel>` tags with `<div>`, everything is ok. But with the `<card-panel>` tag, the $scope used if the card-panel scope and not my-controller $scope.

javascript

```
app = angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.directive('cardPanel', function () {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div style="background:#fff" layout-margin layout-padding><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myContent = '';

  $scope.onChangeListener = function() {
    console.log($scope.myContent);
    console.log("toto");
  }


});
```

html

```
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak style="background:#f1f1f1" layout>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <card-panel layout-margin>
    <h1>MyDemo</h1>

    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label> demo </label>
      <input ng-change="onChangeListener()" ng-model="myContent"> </input>
    </md-input-contanier>
  </card-panelr>    
  </div>
</div>


  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Ok can I do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to solve this problem by using controller as syntax. With controllerAs syntax, there is no confusion about scope.

Here is the working [code](http://codepen.io/vanbergcamp/pen/VeEgEq?editors=1010)

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController as myctrl">
  <card-panel layout-margin>
    <h1>MyDemo</h1>
    
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label> demo </label>
      
      <input ng-change="myctrl.onChangeListener()" ng-model="myctrl.myContent"/> 
    </md-input-contanier>
  </card-panelr>    
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.myContent = '';
  
  vm.onChangeListener = function() {
   
    console.log(vm.myContent);
    console.log("toto");
    
  }
  
  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

> What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that
>   hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not
>   something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal
>   inheritance works.

Please see updated [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVzvGg?editors=1011)

I've changed scope.mycontent = 'text' to scope.mycontent = {val: 'text'}.

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myContent = {val: ''};

  $scope.onChangeListener = function() {
    console.log($scope.myContent.val);
    console.log("toto");
  }
});
```